# Self-Served Password Reset (Embedded Password Reset sample) does not prepopulate the email field with what the user has already entered in email field

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

When using the Self-Served Password Reset (Embedded Password Reset sample), if the email field has already been populated by the user, and they click "Forgot your password" link, in the Reset password flow the user is prompted to enter the email again.

Is there a way to prepopulate it with what the user has already entered in the email field?

Comment: I think that's by behaviour what adb2c provides and can't be tweaked  as forgot password flow is independent of login flow

Comment: @user2903316 It looks like that, but let's see if there something that can be done by the MS guys replying here.